# Given $\int _0 ^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)^a} =1, \ \ a =?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Given $\int_0^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)^a} =1$ what is the value of  $a$?.

I know that $\int_0^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} =1$.

Are there any other solutions?

Could you help me?

Comment: Hint: Find the anti-derivative of $\frac{1}{(1+x)^\alpha}$

Comment: If you know that $a=2$ works you are done. If $b <2 <c$ then $\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^b}>  \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}>  \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^c}$.

Comment: Thank you. (The same inequalities hold for $x \in [0, \infty)$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution: $$\int_0^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)^a} =1$$
$$\therefore \int_0^{+ \infty} (1+x)^{-a} =1$$
$$ \therefore \frac {(1+x)^{1-a}}{1-a}|_0^{+ \infty} =1$$
$$ \therefore \frac {1-a}{(1+x)^{1-a}}|_0^{+ \infty} =1$$
$$\therefore \frac{1-a}{\infty}-\frac{1-a}{1}=1$$
$$\therefore -(1-a)=1$$
**Your answer:** $$\therefore a=2$$

Comment: You should problem put the $|_0^{+\infty}$ to the left of the equal sign - that notation just looks odd.

Comment: ok, i'll put it, thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstood. In general, the expression should be: $f(x)|_0^{+\infty} = 1$.  There is no meaning to $|f(X)=1|_{0}^{+\infty}$, or to this new notation.

Comment: oh well, ok i'll do that, think it has the same meaning though

Comment: No, $|f(x)=1|_a^b$ is meaningless - it doesn't mean anything - it implies you are evaluating the equality $f(x)=1$ t $x=a$ and $x=b$, which is confusion. Also, there shoulding be any bar to the left. We don't write $|f(x)|_a^b$, we write $f(x)|_a^b$. With the bar to the left, it implies an absolute value function.

Comment: There's an actual error in your logic due to your abuse of notation. It is not true that if $f(x)|_a^b = 1$ then $\frac{1}{f(x)}|_a^b = 1$.

Comment: You also error in saying that $(1+x)^{1-a}$ is $\infty$ when $x$ is infinity. If $a>1$ then $1-a<0$ and therefore $(1+x)^{1-a}\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$. This error cancelled out the error that I mentioned in the previous comment.